# How can I set multiple local notification prior 30 minutes based on db value?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, alarmmanager, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I have **3 questions**:

1. I have **2 tables category and task**.
   category table contains the following fields

> id(int), name(text), status(int))

[image]

and the task table contains following fields:

> id(int), category_id(Foreign_key referenced from category table),
> name(text), createdDate(datetime), modifiedDate(datetime),
> dueDate(timestamp)

[image]

I **have to notify the user 30 minutes before the dueDate(timestamp)**, in my case there will be **n no of tasks for the same time** so I have to show local notification for all the tasks. How can I achieve this?

2. For both the category and task I'm having the edit and delete functionality with context option. If I **update the task the local notification should change accordingly**. How can I achieve this?
3. Onclick the notification, it should **redirect to the corresponding task page** which is a child activity of Category(MainActivity or Parent activity). How can I achieve this?

> Note: For this app I'm using SQLite local storage. One notification should not override another notification by any chance.

Comment: one question at the time!

Comment: thanks for your comment, yeah i can understand but to give clear idea about my issue is my intention.

Comment: the question is well written,sb with sqllite experience will contact you shortly :P

Answer (score 1):

1. Run a scheduler in 1 minute interval and compare the `due date` for 30 minutes difference each minute.
2. When ever it matches just create a notification with `task_id` (Of matched row) as
   `notification id`.
3. Keep all the data you want to display on task page in a bundle.
4. Put that bundle as extra in the Intent containing the activity (Task page).
5. Keep that Intent in a Pending Intent.
6. Attach that pendingIntent object with your notification builder like `mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIndent)`.
7. Issue the notification.

As all the `task_id` (Assigned as `Notification_ID`) are unique hence one notification will not override another notification by any chance.